# How to include multiple tables from the same table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a bunch of simple tables/classes. It's zero-to-one relationship.

(Contact has one Type and one Account. Account has one Type, Category, PaymentMethod, Invoice. Keys etc omitted for brevity)

```
class Contact {
    Type MyType;
    Account MyAccount;
}

class Account {
    Type MyType;
    Category MyCategory;
    PaymentMethod MyPayment;
    InvoicingMethod MyMethod;
}

class Type {
     Guid id;
     string name;
}

class Category {
    Guid id;
    string name;
}

class PaymentMethod {
    Guid id;
    string name;
}

class InvoicingMethod {
    Guid id;
    string name;
}
```

How do I `.include()` this mess?

The code below is the only combination I could find which works, but it's verbose and weird:

```
context.Contacts.Where(...)
            .Include(c => c.MyType)
            .Include(c => c.Account)
              .ThenInclude(a => a.MyCategory)
            .Include(c => c.Account)         // Duplicated for next line
              .ThenInclude(a => a.MyType)
            .Include(c => c.Account)         // Duplicated for next line
              .ThenInclude(a => a.MyPayment)
            .Include(c => c.Account)         // Duplicated for next line
              .ThenInclude(a => a.MyMethod)
```

Any way to make this less verbose? Or even better, I'd rather just be telling EF to include whatever it needs to eager load all relations.

Having to include everything like this seems contra-productive and prone to errors, so I suspect there is an easier solution for this.

Comment: Why not use just `ontext.Contacts.Include(c => c.MyType).Include(c => c.MyAccount)` ? `Include` is used to specify which types should be eagerly loaded, it doesn't generate the relation. Behind the scenes, EF will try to rehydrate the graph based on the IDs. That's how you can load a self-referencing hierarchy table without infinite `Include`s

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When I do it like that, `Contact.MyAccount.MyCategory` is not populated (it's `null`), whereas with the code in the question it works.

Comment: Add the category too then. Add only enough `Include`s to include the types you want. You don't need to follow cycles.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do that because of compilation error: `Contacts.Include(c => c.MyType).Include(c => c.MyAccount).Include(a => a.MyCategory)` because `a` in this context is a Contact not an Account.

Comment: You already posted in your question that `ThenInclude` works. The actual problem in the question is that you tried to add extra `Includes`. Don't add the extra `Includes`. At the very least provide a *minimal and complete* example, something that can be copied in LinqPad or dotnetfiddle to reproduce and fix the problem

Comment: Yes, the first example in the question works, and it's the only combination I could get to work. Your solution doesn't I'm afraid. The example is complete (except for the class definitions which is secondary to the problem).

Comment: Could you pls publish all your classes(not all properties, just main ones). This way we could test it and found a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose better `Include` usage:

```cs
await context.Contacts
            .Include(c => c.MyType)
            .Include(c => c.MyAccount.MyCategory)
            .Include(c => c.MyAccount.MyType)
            .Include(c => c.MyAccount.MyPayment)
            .Include(c => c.MyAccount.MyMethod)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Will update answer later if it is still needed syntax shown in question. I think it is possible to do something like that but implementation may take some time:

```cs
await context.Contacts
            .Include(c => c.MyType)
            .Include(c => c.MyAccount)
               .ThenIncludeInline(a => a.MyCategory)
               .ThenIncludeInline(a => a.MyType)   
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Your first example seems to work actually. The second fails, `ThenIncludeInline()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Second one is sample how it may looks like. Implementation may take some time, so just asked maybe first one is enough.